# Why are derived functors triangulated?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C'$ be an additive functor of abelian categories, and assume that the right derived functor $RF:\text D(\mathcal C)\to\text D(\mathcal C')$ exists (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/265098/461) for the definition of $RF$).

On p. 330 of the book **Categories and Sheaves** by Kashiwara and Schapira it is claimed that $RF$ is triangulated.

I'm unable to prove this.

I'm not even able to show that $RF$ is additive.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the (non-commutative) diagram
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text K(\mathcal C)&\overset{\text K(F)}{\to}&\text K(\mathcal C')\\ 
{\scriptstyle Q}\downarrow&&\downarrow\scriptstyle  Q'\\ 
\text D(\mathcal C)&\underset{RF}{\to}&\text D(\mathcal C').
\end{matrix}
$$

We have 
$$
RF(X)\simeq\operatorname*{colim}_{Y\to X}\ \text K(F)(Y),
$$ 
where $Y\to X$ runs over the morphisms from $Y$ to $X$ in $\text D(\mathcal C)$. Using this expression for $RF(X)$ it is easy to see that $RF$ commutes with finite products. By Proposition 8.2.15 p. 173 of **Categories and Sheaves** by Kashiwara and Schapira, this implies that $RF$ is additive.

As $RF$ commutes with finite products, it commutes with mapping cones, and is thus triangulated.

(We have implicitly used the fact that $\text K(\mathcal C)$ and $\text D(\mathcal C)$ have the same set of objects, that $Q$ acts on this set as the identity, and that the same holds for $\mathcal C'$.)